# PHP using cURL: unable to pass cookies to Iframe

Tags: php, curl, iframe, session-cookies

Been searching for a while without sucess for a solution. Also, I'm really not experimented in php and REST API, so apologies for any newbie mistakes.

I need to
1) send a POST request to a server and get cookies associated to my login
2) reuse these cookies with url based on that same server, which runs a report.

To perform this I use php and cURL. The below script works fine:

```
    <?php
$homeurl = "http://localhost:8080/pentaho/j_spring_security_check?j_username=admin&j_password=admin&locale=en_US";
$reporturl = 'http://localhost:8080/pentaho/api/repos/:public:IframeDossier:IframeTest.prpt/viewer?label=fin';


$cookie_jar = tempnam('/Users/pierre/Vrac','cookie');
    if (!file_exists(realpath($cookie_jar))) touch($cookie_jar);

//login and get cookies
$ch = curl_init($homeurl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_jar);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
$return = curl_exec($ch);

// run report url using cookies
echo "execution report";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_jar);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $reporturl);
$page = curl_exec($ch);
echo $page;


curl_close($ch);

?>
```

I get the expected return:

"*HTTP/1.1 100 HTTP/1.1 415 Set-Cookie: session-expiry=1542901561740; Path=/ Set-Cookie: server-time=1542894361740; Path=/ Content-Length: 0 Date: Thu, 22 Nov 2018 13:46:01 GMT Connection: close*"

now instead I would like to embed $reporturl into an Iframe. I've built the following Iframe:

```
<iframe id="inlineFrameExample"
    title="Inline Frame Example"
    width="1000"
    height="2000" src="http://localhost:8080/pentaho/api/repos/:public:IframeDossier:IframeTest.prpt/viewer?label=fin">
    </iframe>
```

My Iframe runs correctly when I call its url.

I am now calling the Iframe url in my code. so

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $reporturl);
```

becomes

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, http://localhost:8080/IframeTest.html);
```

the problem is that now, my browser asks for authentication, while my Iframe should already have this authentication using cookies retrieved in the first step of the code. I must be doing something wrong, but cant' figure out what... any help much appreciated.

thanks

Comment: why you have *415 Unsupported Media Type* in curl answer? AND https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757071/php-debugging-curl

Comment: thanks for your comment. using CURLOPT_VERBOSE, I see that cookies are correctly added and set when calling initial value of $reporturl is used. when changing the value of $report_url to http://localhost:8080/IframeTest.html, cookies are not retrieved.

Comment: Did you check what is in `cookie_jar` file? Cookies have right `path`? And it probably means you're using the same CURL instance and you're re-adding cookie_jar. (and CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER)